# Change value of parent component variable using $parent but not reflected in interpolation syntax in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
Child component
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Child Component</h3>
  <div>
         <button   @click="changeValue()">change Parent </button>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return{}
 },
 methods: {
  changeValue() {
    this.$parent.model[somekey] = somevalue
  }
 }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Parent component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Parent Component</h3>
   <div>
      {{model}} **<!--value is not refleted here -->**
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return{
     model: {}
    }
  }
 }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

changing value of parent variable using changeValue method of child component  but not reflected in parent interpolation syntax ({{model}}). but when i access in parent method i got the updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue cannot detect when properties are added or removed from an object. Read [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Define the property upfront:

```js
data: {
  model: {
    foo: null
  }
}
```

```js
this.$parent.model.foo = somevalue
```

If you need to add a property dynamically, then you need to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Answer (score 0):

You should emit event from children and handle in parent instead of changing it directly in children. It will be easier for you to manage the data

For example

**Child component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Child Component</h3>
  <div>
         <button @click="changeValue()">change Parent </button>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return{}
 },
 methods: {
  changeValue() {
    this.$emit('changeValue', someValue)
  }
 }
</script>
```

**Parent component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Parent Component</h3>
   <div>
      {{model}}
  </div>
  <child-component @changeValue="changeValue" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return{
     model: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeValue (newValue) {
      this.model[someKey] = newValue
      this.model = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model))
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```